# The post error "You need at least 2 reputation to post more than 10 links." is worded/implemented backwards

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, error-message

I tried making a longer post on Stack Overflow and kept receiving this message even though I was sure I was under 10 links. It's now kind of clear that the wording is just backwards and intends to read:

> You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: The developer that did it wasn't nearly as think as you drunk he was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers were inserted in the incorrect locations in a format string.

Corrected so the error message makes sense.

This will be in the next build.